# How to pass props to children with functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having a trouble with passing props to children in functional react. My `{children}` is a  `Details` component like below:

```
<SidebarPage>
   {children}
</SidebarPage>
```

```
const Details = () => {}
```

how can I pass props in way that, I put props to `{children}` and I receive this props in `Details` component? Is this even workable?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: render the component and pass children as property`<Details children={children}/>` , `const details = (props) => {}`

Comment: @charchit thanks but no, your solution is a workaround and I can't do this in this way

Answer (score 1):

You can pass component as prop, something like -

```
const SidebarPage = ({ChildComponent}) => {
  const props = { name: "X" };

  return <ChildComponent {...props} />
}

const Details = (props) => {}

<SidebarPage ChildComponent={Details} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use cloneElement to add new props to a component children

```
const newProps = {aProp: "aProp"} ;

return (
<SidebarPage>
   {React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
     return React.cloneElement(child, {
       newProps,
    }, null)
   }
</SidebarPage>
)
```

Comment: More explications and examples here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-react-cloneelement-function/

Comment: bad news here =( -> Argument of type '{ newProps: { handle: () => void; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<unknown> & Attributes'